# How configure TomEE and JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

sorry for my bad english, (Im french :-D).
I want work with TomEE for JPA, but my configuration is bad i think.
I receive a exception when i try to connecte to my database (Mysql).

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="elevage" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>elevage</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>elevageUnmanaged</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>com.test.ejb.BeanAnimal</class>

    <properties>

        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mysql" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

tomee.xml

```
<Resource id="elevage" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl             jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elevage2?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney&amp;useSSL=false
    UserName            root
    Password            pass
    JtaManaged          true
    DefaultAutoCommit   false
</Resource>

<Resource id="elevageUnmanaged" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl             jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elevage2?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney&amp;useSSL=false
    UserName            root
    Password            pass
    JtaManaged          false
</Resource>
```

Exception

```
AVERTISSEMENT: Unexpected exception from beforeCompletion; transaction will roll back 
<openjpa-2.4.1-r422266:1730418 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: user lacks privilege or object not found: OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE {SELECT SEQUENCE_VALUE FROM OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE} [code=-5501, state=42501]
```

Request is a "SELECT" and i want take all data in my database. I have see documentation but the problem persiste.

Thank all for your answer !
(if you need more file, tell me :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time tearing my hair, I found a solution, if it can save time, here it is:

2 Configurations!

**In development:**

**tomee.xml** is not used, it is necessary to configure **openejb.xml** whose path is specified in the eclipse console, attention, the access is by hidden file

Path for my machine (Linux):

```
 /home/user/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/conf/openejb.xml
```

At the bottom of the file, you have section "Resource", the configuration is identical to tomee.xml (you can find documentation at this adress : [documentation for configuration tomee.xml](http://tomee.apache.org/application-resources.html)

**In production:**

we forget **openejb.xml**, a configuration is identical but in **tomee.xml**

to finish, here is my configuration:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="elevage" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>MyDataBase</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>MyDataBaseUnmanaged</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>com.test.ejb.BeanAnimal</class>
    <!-- <class>com.test.ejb.BeanUser</class>-->


    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mysql" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

openejb.xml (in development) and tomee.xml (in production)

```
<Resource id="MyDataBase" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elevage?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney&amp;useSSL=false
    UserName root
    Password pass
    JtaManaged true
</Resource>

<Resource id="MyDataBaseUnmanaged" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elevage?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney&amp;useSSL=false
    UserName root
    Password pass
    JtaManaged false
</Resource>
```